# Does .net trace processing have equivalent or better event parsing support as ETW2JSON?

Tags: .net-traceprocessing

I've looked through much of the documentation on trace processing and ETW in general but still feel as though I'm lacking some specifics. Does the Trace Processing library contain support to process all events that are part of a `.etl` file? For instance, [ETW2JSON](https://github.com/Microsoft/ETW2JSON) claims to support the following and provides a library to deserialize events:

> Windows MOF Classes events, Windows Vista Manifest events and EventSource .NET events. It also understands events that XPERF (WPR) adds as part of its merging process (to give PDB information) for profiler tools like the Windows Performance Recorder.

Does the Trace Processing library provide equivalent or better support for processing all types of events from a `.etl` file?

For instance, let's say I'm processing via generic events.

```cs
using (ITraceProcessor trace = TraceProcessor.Create(etlPath))
{
    IPendingResult<IGenericEventDataSource> genericEvents = trace.UseGenericEvents();

    trace.Process();

    IGenericEventDataSource genericEventDataSource = genericEvents.Result;

    foreach (IGenericEvent gevent in genericEventDataSource.Events)
    {
        // process event
    }
}
```

With the above code, does this give me access to **all** events in a `.etl` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I am a developer at Microsoft who works on the TraceProcessor project.)

I don't have experience with the ETW2JSON project, so I can't speak to comparisons.

There are four [ETW provider types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/writing-events):

- MOF/Classic - Events available in the [IClassicEventDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windows.eventtracing.events.iclassiceventdatasource?view=trace-processor-dotnet-1.0)
- Windows Trace Preprocessor (WPP) - Events available in the [IWindowsTracePreprocessorDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windows.eventtracing.events.iwindowstracepreprocessordatasource?view=trace-processor-dotnet-1.0)
- Manifested - Events available in the [IGenericEventDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windows.eventtracing.events.igenericeventdatasource?view=trace-processor-dotnet-1.0)
- TraceLogging - Events available in the [IGenericEventDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windows.eventtracing.events.igenericeventdatasource?view=trace-processor-dotnet-1.0)

(You can use the [IsTraceLogging property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windows.eventtracing.events.igenericevent.istracelogging?view=trace-processor-dotnet-1.0) on [IGenericEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windows.eventtracing.events.igenericevent?view=trace-processor-dotnet-1.0) to distingush between manifested and TraceLogging events.)

I don't know of a type of event in the trace that wouldn't appear in one of those three data sources, but if you find something missing, please let me know.

Comment: I know about manifested and the classic ETW events. But what are WPP and TraceLogging events? How and by whom are they typically written? Any documentation links?

Comment: The four event types differ in three main ways that are of interest to event authors:
1) How you actually fire the events with the right metadata in the payload in your code
2) How big each event on disk in the final ETL
3) How you consume them when processing ETLs

Classic events have no fixed payload schema, and therefore it's up to the firing code and the consuming code to both know/agree on a schema. This lets the event be small in the trace because there's no metadata about the event schema taking space, but it makes consuming/decoding the events less straightforward.

Comment: Manifested events fix the payload schema in the form of a manifest file. This again lets the event be small in the trace because there's no schema metadata, and also helps with versioning because different event versions can be documented in the manifest. However, this requires the manifest to be present for decoding, proactively updated when the firing code is changed to include more/different metadata in the payload, and thus can complicate the dev loop for iterating/making changes.

Comment: [TraceLogging events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tracelogging/tracelogging-using-tracelogging) bundle the event schema data along with the event data in the trace. That means that the events are generally bigger, and firing them generally less performant than with manifested/classic events, but it means that there's more flexibility for decoding because the schema info is guaranteed to be present. It also helps with the dev loop because there's no manifest file to keep updated. Versioning is trickier, though, which can cause issues when decoding.

Comment: [WPP events](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/wpp-software-tracing) is sort of halfway between manifested events and TraceLogging events. They use a "printf" style command for firing events, which makes it very easy to write in your code. Like manifested events, decoding WPP events requires a separate file. Like tracelogging events that file is generally created as part of the build process, so a separate manifest need not be maintained. (See [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/message-analyzer/loading-wpp-generated-events) for more about decoding).

Comment: I don't have visibility into every teams' practices at Microsoft, but from my own experience I would say that very old providers use classic events. Newer providers use manifested events. And the current general practice is to use TraceLogging events. WPP has some nice characteristics around event authorship, but the separate file needed for decoding often makes that process more complicated. TraceLogging seems to me to be the current best answer where a manifest isn't present, but again take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answers!